# How to toggle each <li> one by one?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an HTMl which is like this:-

```
<li rel="leftmenu-root-add_section" class="accordion">
                <a href="javascript:void(0)">
                    <i class="fa fa-plus"></i><span style="font-size: 20px"><b>Add</b></span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <div class="panel"><ul class="test">
                    <li rel="leftmenu-root-add_post">
                        <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>admin/post/add_post">
                            <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> <span>Post</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li rel="leftmenu-root-add_announcement">
                        <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>admin/announcement/add_announcement">
                            <i class="fa fa-volume-up"></i> <span>Announcement</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li rel="leftmenu-root-add_page">
                        <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>admin/page/add_page">
                            <i class="fa fa-file-o"></i> <span>Pages</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li rel="leftmenu-root-add_tag">
                        <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>admin/tag/add_tag">
                            <i class="fa fa-tags"></i> <span>Tag</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>

               </ul>
               </div>
```

I want to click on "`accordion`", and each of the menu under the `<div class="panel"><ul class="test">` get hidden.

I tried with this  code, but something is going wrong.

```
$('.accordion').on('click',function(){
            var ulist = $(this).closest('div').find('ul');
            alert(ulist.attr('class'));
            alert('Hii');
        });
```

### EDIT:-

The given suggesstion are fantastic in this question. However, there are something more I would like to request.

The div is getting hide and visible. I want to take sometransition time more like the `SlideUp` & `SildeDown` function of jQuery.

However, instead of hiding the total div or all the `<li>`s at once, I would like one li to get hide, wait for some fraction of time and then hide the next.

Comment: I updated my answer. Change delay as you want

Comment: @Saswat: check my answer, I've updated.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
$(function() {
  $('.accordion').on('click', function() {
   var ulist = $(this).next('.panel').find("ul.test");
   ulist.toggle();
  });
});
```

See it working in the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s9oLL771/).

The explanation is that you need to do the event binding after the DOM loads, so you need to put your code inside a `$(funciton(){...`. It's like a `$("document").ready();`

Then, inside your event binding, you select the next `.panel` to the `.accordion` you've clicked. And once you have it, you search for the `ul.test` that you want to hide. Made this, you call `toggle` so each time you click on the element it will show/hide the ul.

**EDIT**

If you want that efect you should pic each `li` and hide one by one adding a delay. Like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/s9oLL771/5/):

```
$(function() {
  $('.accordion').on('click', function() {
     var ulist = $(this).next('.panel').find("ul.test li");
     var count = 0;
     var delay = 300;

     $.each(ulist, function(){
        $(this).delay(delay*count).fadeToggle();
        count++;
     });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.accordion').on('click',function(){
   $(this).siblings('div').find('ul').toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this snippet.

**Edit 1**
**To hide the li one by one.**

Used slideToggle as per your requirement.

```js
$('.accordion').on('click',function(){
   //Get all li
   var liVar = $(this).next('div.panel').children('ul').find('li');
   //Call function for interval
   callFunction(liVar);
});
var interval;
//Function for interval to hide one by one
function callFunction(liVar){
  var temp=0;  
  interval = window.setInterval(function(){
     //Clear interval
     if(temp >= liVar.length)
     {
       clearInterval(interval);
     }
     liVar.eq(temp).slideToggle(1000);
     temp += 1;
   }, 1000);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li rel="leftmenu-root-add_section" class="accordion">
                <a href="javascript:void(0)">
                    <i class="fa fa-plus"></i><span style="font-size: 20px"><b>Add</b></span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <div class="panel"><ul class="test">
                    <li rel="leftmenu-root-add_post">
                        <a href="javascript:void(0)">
                            <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> <span>Post</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li rel="leftmenu-root-add_announcement">
                        <a href="javascript:void(0)">
                            <i class="fa fa-volume-up"></i> <span>Announcement</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li rel="leftmenu-root-add_page">
                        <a href="javascript:void(0)">
                            <i class="fa fa-file-o"></i> <span>Pages</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li rel="leftmenu-root-add_tag">
                        <a href="javascript:void(0)">
                            <i class="fa fa-tags"></i> <span>Tag</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>

               </ul>
               </div>
<li rel="leftmenu-root-add_section" class="accordion">
                <a href="javascript:void(0)">
                    <i class="fa fa-plus"></i><span style="font-size: 20px"><b>Edit</b></span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <div class="panel"><ul class="test">
                    <li rel="leftmenu-root-add_post">
                        <a href="javascript:void(0)">
                            <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> <span>Post</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li rel="leftmenu-root-add_announcement">
                        <a href="javascript:void(0)">
                            <i class="fa fa-volume-up"></i> <span>Announcement</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li rel="leftmenu-root-add_page">
                        <a href="javascript:void(0)">
                            <i class="fa fa-file-o"></i> <span>Pages</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li rel="leftmenu-root-add_tag">
                        <a href="javascript:void(0)">
                            <i class="fa fa-tags"></i> <span>Tag</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>

               </ul>
               </div>
```